# Web server raspberry pi no loading css (or anything from the root dir)

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, webserver

I've set up an apache web server on my raspberry pi and I've gotten it to display the html, but getting it to access any other files on the root is proving difficult. My file structure is `site/<html|css|resources>` and I can point my sites-available/000-default.conf at `site/html` just fine and get only the html, and if I point it at the root `site` when I load the web page I get a list of the files and then if I click on `html` it loads everything including the images and css just fine. Here's some of the config files I tried messing with:

`apache2.conf:`

```
<Directory /var/www/site/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

`000-default.conf:`

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/site/html
```

`default-ssl.conf:`

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/site
```

I couldn't manage to find something that worked for me online but any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `DocumentRoot` defines the directory under which the site content files are stored.  Therefore the user that runs your apache must have read permissions on the files, and traverse on the directories.  Another point, the references in your code must match the directory structure under your `DocumentRoot`.  Ex. if your links say `css/mysite.css`, there must be a file under `DocumentRoot`/css/mysite.css.  Since you are getting a list of files, and not the html rendering of the pages, look into `DirectoryIndex` for the default html page to display on empty requests.

Comment: Thank you, I don't really know what I'm doing yet but changing the directory index to the path of index.html made it work perfectly